# Cant Access Website - Changed HTTP to HTTPs

Tags: redirect, https, http

Was playing around with settings and changed HTTP to HTTPs.  I'm now getting a message that says "Index of /".  Any idea how to change it back to HTTP or login to the website?

Comment: The idea is to revert settings. It's impossible to guess what have you done to face the problem.

Comment: @David Does your hosting uses a control panel, like for example DirectAdmin or cPanel? Check my answer, sometimes it's just a setting.

Answer (score 1):

By default web servers / your hosting serves files from **HTTPS** from a separate folder. This means that there are actually two directories on the server for hosting your website files:

For example

- **public_html** – the standard "public" folder for **HTTP** requests
- **private_html** – the standard "private" folder for **HTTPS** requests (e.g. secure content)

I don't know if your web hosting uses a control panel like DirectAdmin or cPanel. Usually, you need to configure HTTPS to use the same directory for HTTP requests.

### DirectAdmin:

> **Step 1:** Login to DirectAdmin and Choose the "Domain Setup" Link
>   On the next page select the domain that you would like to make these changes for.
>
> **Step 2:** Choose the Symbolic Link Option
>   On the following page that displays the directory options, choose the second option at the bottom to Use a Symbolic Link for data in both directories, then click Save:
>
> After making this change **public_html** will both serve **HTTP** and **HTTPS** and you only need to upload your files to the **public_html** directory.

See for more info: https://my.fastwebengine.com/knowledgebase/131/How-do-I-disable-the-privatehtml-directory-in-order-to-only-use-the-publichtml-directory.html